# adding Json to mutable array resolves in crash

Tags: ios, arrays, json

Hello guys I am new to Xcode/iOS developing

I trying to add json data to the mutable array , and it results in app crash :(
so far here is my code:

```
if(! [defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"])
    [defaults setObject:[PersonsFromSearch objectAtIndex:index] forKey:@"Person1"];
else
{
    NSMutableArray *Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    id object = [defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"];
    Array = [object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ? object : @[object];
    [Array addObject:[PersonsFromSearch objectAtIndex:index]];//crash here :((
    [Array moveObjectFromIndex:[Array count] toIndex:0];

}
```

Crash Dump:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb4d380'
*** First throw call stack:

what is wrong here ? can you please help me to resolve this issue

Array contains this (Json?)

```
{
   Address = "\U05d3\U05e8\U05da \U05d4\U05e9\U05dc\U05d5\U05dd 53";
   CellPhone = "052-3275381";
   EMail = "editor@pc.co.il";
   EnglishPerson = "Yehuda Konfortes";
   FaceBookLink = "";
   Fax1 = "03-7330703";
   Fax2 = "";
   FileNAme = "100050.jpg";
   HomeEMail = "";
   HomeFax = "";
   HomePhone1 = "";
   HomePhone2 = "";
   PersonID = 100050;
   PersonName = "\U05d9\U05d4\U05d5\U05d3\U05d4   \U05e7\U05d5\U05e0\U05e4\U05d5\U05e8\U05d8\U05e1";
   Phone1 = "03-7330733";
   Phone2 = "";
   ZipCode = "";
 }
```

Comment: This is not an array. It is one dictionary. What do you want to sort? Or you just want to add all values to array?

Comment: I want to have Array of objects like that (no need help in sorting thanks).
I want Array[0] to be {address…. , cellphone…,email…}
Array[1] {address…,cellphone…,email...}

Comment: if my Array contain dictionary so i want to make Array of dictionaries
I hope it is possible !?

Comment: I have updated my answer. But I think that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv jsonserialization function returns dictionary ?

Comment: It may return NSDictionary, NSArray, NSNumber, NSString or NSNull

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv Thank you very much for help !
I appreciate this , in the end I solved it. the solution is in my comment , copy paste it to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it works as well as your solution, but uses modern syntax.

Comment: I don't know why I got down voted it is not trivial question , and no duplicates , I searched for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"];` returns dictionary but not array.
So you can't use `addObject` method.

**UPD**
You may resolve this crash by creation array with a single object.
Here is updated code:

```
NSMutableArray *Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
id object = [defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"];
Array = [object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] ? [object mutableCopy] : [@[object] mutableCopy];
[Array addObject:[PersonsFromSearch objectAtIndex:index]];//crash here :((
[Array moveObjectFromIndex:[Array count] toIndex:0];
```

Comment: any possible solutions ?

Comment: Log [defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"]; and tell what you want to do.

Comment: I want to add this object to the Array so I can sort it etc.
because i have ~50 object like this in the array , but I want to store only favourites which are only 10.

Comment: I don't know what is this you added , but I still crashing in a very same row, why do you think it is wrong ?

do I have to swap line 2 and 3 ?

Comment: It's crashing because index > 0 and array contains only 1 object. I think that it's wrong because Parson1 should be array, but it is dictionary.

Comment: So I should init it to be array of 10 ?

Comment: You should somewhere have code like this: [defaults setObject:array forKey:@"Person1"]. Make sure that you set array.

Comment: PersonsFromSearch contains 25 objects in this run. it should work because i call this code from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: What is new reason of crash?

Comment: yes I have it , I will update the question now , I also can log the Array after the assignment , so it is inited.

Comment: Same story :( the PersonsFromSearch is initialised from the jsonSerialization maybe it is the problem ?
but still i have the array in PersonsFromSearch, can I cast dictionary like in C ? [Array addObject:(Object*)[PersonsFromSearch objectAtIndex:index]];

Comment: You can't cast it. The issue is somewhere else.

Comment: I solved IT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        NSMutableArray *Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        id object = [defaults objectForKey:@"Person1"];
        [Array addObject:object];
        id object1 = [PersonsFromSearch objectAtIndex:index];
        [Array addObject:object1];

Comment: Right. I forgot to change this @[object] to this [@[object] mutableCopy]

Comment: It feels like void* in normal C ))

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray *_arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDictionary *results = **PASS JSON Value**;

[_arr add object:[results objectforkey:@“Address”]];
[_arr add object:[results objectforkey:@“CellPhone”]];

Comment: No , I don't want to make an Array from the data ,I want to make array 
of JSONS like that.